# Controller Action cannot be called from $.Ajax javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

In MVC, I have written an action in the controller for getting values. The action is as follows..

```
public void poolshapepdf(List<String> values)
        {
            ...
        }
```

To pass the parameter values to the controller action i pass the values from javascript..

the code is the below,

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: rootDir + "IngroundCalculation/poolshapepdf",
        data: { values: collectionPSElmt },
        traditional: true,
    });

Here collectionPSElmt is an array. 
  collectionPSElmt[index] = poolshapeValue[index] + "-" + psFeet[index] + "-" + psInch[index];
```

Here the issue is the controller action cannot be called from the javascript $.Ajax(..).
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the name of your controller `IngroundCalculation`? What is the value of `rootDir`?

Comment: the value of rootDir="/";

Answer (score 0):

You calling the controller by POST and JSON data:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult poolshapepdf(DataClass[] items)
  {

  }
```

Comment: It's a class of your object passed in JQuery Call in data field.

Comment: I had him navigate the URL and it's not found. Something is up with his routing.

Answer (score 0):

Now, make a proper call to your url.
specify the data type as json and always go for success function.
using that you can easily crack the report.

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>   url: '@Url.Action("poolshapepdf", "IngroundCalculation")',
>   type: "POST",
>   dataType: 'json',
>   data: collectionPSElmt ,
>   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>   success: function (result) {             
>          alert("Working..");
>   }
> ```
>
> });

And at Controller Side,

> [HttpPost]
>
> public JsonResult poolshapepdf(DataClass[] items)
>
> {
>
> ```
>       // Your Code here....
> ```
>
> }